# WordPress mini-logo looks like Wikipedia's "W"

Tags: feature-request

I'm a regular stackexchanger of other sites, and I just want to let you guys know that the 'W' of your mini-logo that appears under the "Hot Network Questions" looks an awful like Wikipedia's "W" (and I got confused)

[image]

Perhaps someone who has some spare time could change it?  My suggestion is to use "WP".

Comment: As far as I know this is not something in our control. maybe asking directly the SE overlords will be a better avenue for that request. And I agree it is confusing for me as well.

Comment: Just a reminder that we can't use the official WordPress logo for trademark reasons before anybody gets any bright ideas

Comment: Would it be helpful to maybe change the icon to have a circle around it?